# R - Block resampling and saving samples in a list

Tags: r, resampling

I have a vector on which I want to do block resampling to get, say, 1000 samples of the same size of the vector, and then save all this samples in a list.

This is the code that performs normal resampling, i.e. randomly draws one observation per time, and saves the result in a list:

```
myvector <- c(1:200)
mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  mylist[[i]] <- sample(myvector, length(myvector), replace=TRUE)
}
```

I need a code that does exactly the same thing, except that instead of drawing single observations it draws blocks of observations (let's use blocks of dimension equal to 5).

I know there are packages that perform bootstrap operations, but I don't need statistics or confidence intervals or anything, just all the samples in a list. Both overlapping and non-overlapping blocks are ok, so the code for just one of the two procedures is enough. Of course, if you are so kind to give me the code for both it's appreciated. Thanks to anybody who can help me with this.

Comment: What happens if `length(myvector)` is not divisible by your block dimension? So for example, if `myvector` were to contain `201` entries, how would you sample blocks of `5` elements? Would your final sample consist of `200` elements, or `205` elements?

Comment: With overlapping blocks, this is never a problem, although there is the problem that the first and last observations are less likely to be selected. With non-overlapping blocks it can happen, you're right. In such case one can usa circular block resampling (see for example section 3.3 at page 8 here: http://www.math.chalmers.se/~palbin/BootstrapDependentAndreasSunesson.pdf). If someone has the code to do it he is welcome. Anyway, I plan to use a divisible length.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. This has nothing to do with (non)overlapping blocks. Let me rephrase. If your original sample has `201` elements, how many blocks of `5` elements to you sample? `40` blocks of `5` elements (=`200`), or `41` blocks of `5` elements (=`205`)?

Comment: It has to do with the blocks being overlapping or not because if the blocks overlap it's not a problem if the length is not divisible. For example if you have 5 elements and overlapping blocks of size 3, the possible blocks are: (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5). If in the same situation you want non-overlapping blocks, you have to use circular block resampling, which fixes the issue. How many blocks to sample is up to you. You can have 200 elements divided in 40 blocks of dimension 5 and then just randomly draw 3 of them, or 20 or 500 (rememer that it's a sampling with replacement).

Comment: I agree with the whole (non)overlapping business, but that's not what I've been asking. I think we're missing each other's point. In your example with `5` elements, how large do you expect your final sample to be when sampling blocks of `3` elements? Do you expect to end up with 1 block (i.e. `3` elements), 2 blocks (`6` elements), 3 blocks (`9` elements), ...?

Comment: Ok now I see what you mean. Since I want the new samples to be exactly of the same size of my vector, the length of the vector has to be divisible by the block dimension. I just do not deal with the situation in which this does not happen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've added a solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following? Note that you can use `lapply`, which should be slightly faster than filling the list in a `for` loop in this case.

As reference, here is the case where you sample individual observations.

```
# Sample individual observations
set.seed(2017);
mylist <- lapply(1:1000, function(x) sample(myvector, length(myvector), replace = TRUE));
```

Next we sample blocks of 5 observations.

```
# Sample blocks of n observations
n <- 5;
set.seed(2017);
mylist <- lapply(1:1000, function(x) {
    idx <- sample(1:(length(myvector) - n), length(myvector) / n, replace = TRUE);
    idx <- c(t(sapply(0:(n - 1), function(i) idx + i)));
    myvector[idx];
})
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. I see you used overlapping samples. If you or someone else could also provide a version with non-overlapping samples it would be great, but this already solves my problem.

Comment: @Hanx70 Concerning non-overlapping samples: I'm not sure at the moment how best to implement this; perhaps a simple accept-reject step when sampling the indices, but that won't be very fast/efficient. Maybe somebody else has a better idea...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you're wanting to store the final structure.

The following takes a block dimension, samples your vector by that block size (e.g. 200 element vector with block size 5 gives 40 observations of randomly sampled elements) and adds those blocks to an index of the final list. Using your example, the final result is a list with 1000 entries; each entry containing 40 randomly sampled observations.

```
myvector <- c(1:200)

rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())

block_dimension <- 5

res = list()
for(i in 1:1000) {
    name <- paste('sample_', i, sep='')
    rep_num <- length(myvector) / block_dimension
    all_blocks <- replicate(rep_num, sample(myvector, block_dimension))
    tmp <- split(all_blocks, ceiling(seq_along(all_blocks)/block_dimension))
    res[[name]] <- tmp
    }
```

**Here are the first 6 sampled observations for the first entry:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm afraid it's not what I need. The entire point of this operation is to maintain intact the structure within each block. The code should randomly select blocks, not the elements inside them. Since the vector has elements from 1 to 200, and is splitted in blocks of size 5, each sampled block should contain values like (1,2,3,4,5) or (56,57,58,59,60). Sorry if that wasn't clear. Regarding how to store the result, I would like a list of 1000 entries, with each entry consisting of a vector of 200 values, resulting from the 40 blocks randomly sampled.

Comment: @Hanx70 if you remove the “tmp <- split(....” line, you get your described result. “... a list of 1000 entries, with each entry consisting of a vector of 200 values, resulting from the 40 blocks randomly sampled.” The reason I split them above was so each individual 5 element block could be seen in the final structure.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, assuming blocks consist of contiguous elements of `myvector`, is to pre-define the blocks in rows of a data frame with start/end columns (e.g. `blocks <- data.frame(start=seq(1,96,5),end=seq(5,100,5))`). Create a set of sample indexes (with replacement) from [1:number of blocks] and concatenate values indexing from `myvector` using the start/end values from the defined blocks. You can add randomization within blocks as well, if you need to. This gives you control over the block contents, overlap, size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to perform the task with non-overlapping blocks:

```
myvector <- c(1:200)
n <- 5
mymatrix <- matrix(myvector, nrow = length(myvector)/n, byrow = TRUE)
mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  mylist[[i]] <- as.vector(t(mymatrix[sample(nrow(mymatrix), size = length(myvector)/n, replace = TRUE),]))
}
```